# Copy a git-push to another computer, or perform smaller incremental pushes?

Tags: git, version-control, github, git-extensions

I'm on holidays at present and have been doing some work, committing and pushing to github.
Our internet connection here is pretty bad (wireless point-to-point in the mountains) and drops off very regularly.

I was able to push to github for about a week and a half, but for the past couple of days I haven't been able to. I can push smaller changes made to other repos, but this is a fairly big one I think, and I've been making the situation worse by adding more and more commits.

When I attempt to push (using git extensions under Windows) I get the following error:

> c:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe push "origin" master:master
>   Done
>   FATAL ERROR: Network error: Software caused connection abort
>   fatal: sha1 file '' write error: Broken pipe
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
>   error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:plenderj/myproject.git'

I can see outbound network activity, and then it'll drop off, and some time later git complains. I've probably tried to push about 10 or 15 times now.

Is there a way I can split up what git's attempting to upload into smaller chunks, or can I create some sort of diff file(s), apply them to my computer at home, and then upload from there?
Worst case scenario I copy and paste the whole /src/ folder to a memory stick and just do it from home, but I can't help but think there's a better way. Any suggestions? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `git-format-patch` to build a series of email-able patches that you can apply using `git-apply` at the other end.

see `man git-format-patch` for more details.

To create patches for your changes since you `pull`ed from the master:

```
git format-patch origin/master
```

This creates a series of files you can email or upload.

If you have email set-up for git on your computer, you can email directly using

```
git send-email
```

If you have email set-up for git on the origin, you can apply directly using

```
git am
```

Comment: Thanks. I did this and ended up with 278MB worth of .PATCH files - it's no wonder I could never upload this in one go. I've since rar'd the lot and FTP'd it back home. I'll git-apply the patches when I get home.

Comment: That's pretty big.  You should check you haven't accidentally checked in your object files.

Answer (score 3):

You can also look at your history, pick a revision somewhere on your `master` and then say

```
git push <remote> <revision>:tmp-branch
```

This way you can manually incrementally push changes since git never copies the same object twice. A final `git push <remote> master` will then update the `master` branch.

---

Another option is `git bundle`. You can create a file with your unpushed commits by saying

```
git bundle create my.bundle origin/master..master
```

Then you can transfer this file using some robust method (rsync?) and apply it in the remote repository with a

```
git pull /path/to/my.bundle master
```